# Finding integral of a function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have stumbled upon an exercise that reads thus:

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^0\frac{x^x}{x^3-1}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{2\sqrt3}{9}\pi,$$

and I am guessing it is asking to prove the above equality. Calculating a primitive (indefinite integral, antiderivative) of that function seems quite impossible. My only other idea was to find the power series for $x^x$, which is $x^x=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{i!}x^i\log^i(x)$ according to [Wolfram Alpha](http://bit.ly/xtoxwolfram), somehow prove I can swap series and integral after plugging that series into the integral, and compute each term, but the calculations are really "crazy" for the general term $\int\limits_{-\infty}^0\frac{x^i\log^i(x)}{i!(x^3-1)}\mathrm{d}x$. Note that $i$ is an index, *not* the imaginary unit. I have a hunch this may require some complex analysis, especially since $x^x$ is not *really* defined on those negative numbers, but is *complexly*. Since I can't go anywhere on my own, I thought I'd come here and ask: is there some smart and not overly calculation-y way to compute this?

**Edit:**
It *does* seem that the integral has a complex value. Here is the screenshot of the exercise:

[image]

A a first glance I thought it was a Calculus exercise. Then $x^x$ is not defined for negative numbers, or at least, not for *all* of them. The integral seems to have a complex value as written. So this has become a really misterious exercise. Possible interpretations:

- The real part of the integral is required;
- The integral of the real part is required;
- The imaginary part of the integral is required.

Does any of these get close to the given value?

Comment: The curve would have to be the $[-\infty,0]$ segment of the real axis, which is not closed! So I can't apply that theorem, can I?

Comment: @YourAdHere He obviously means it is not a closed contour

Comment: Hmm. But how do I close a curve that goes to infinity? PS Complex Analysis is one of the courses of my next year's II semester, so I know basically nothing about it :).

Comment: I'm amazed such an integral is possible. But your power series can't be right, at least interpreting $\log(x)$ as a Real function

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, for $x \in (-\infty,0)$, what is the sign of numerator $x^x$? If it is positive, then the integrand is negative!

Comment: The main issue here is how $x^x$ is defined for $x<0$. From $x^x=e^{x\log x}$, assuming that we take the branch of the logarithm for which $\log(-x)=\pi i+\log x$, we are left with $$-\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^x e^{-\pi i x}}{x^3+1}\,dx$$ whose value is neither purely imaginary nor purely real.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio shouldn't that be $x^{-x}$ etc.? If I substitute $t=-x$, reverse the integration limits and place the $-$ of the differential on the denominator, then write $e^{-t\log(-t)}=e^{-t(i\pi+\log(t))}=e^{-t(i\pi)}e^{-t\log(t)}$, the second factor is $t^{-t}$, isn't it?

Comment: @MickG: yes, you are right, there is a $x^{-x}$ in place of $x^x$.

Comment: @achillehui what do you mean? First of all for $x<0$ $x^x$ is either undefined or complex, so what's the point in asking about the _sign_? _negative_ and _positive_ are not defined in the complex field, AFAIK, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_%28mathematics%29) defines _positive_ as $>0$ and _negative_ as $<0$, which is my intuition, and doesn't make sense with complex numbers since we have no order, thus have no $>$ and $<$. And what is the problem with the integrand being negative?

Comment: @DavidPeterson why can't "my power series" (which is more like Wolfram's series) be right? I know that for $x<0$ $\log(x)$ isn't defined for the real function, but then with the complex function it is. So I don't see the problem once we move to complex numbers. It could be that the series is valid only for $x>0$. I have personally never seen that series and just got it from Wolfram.

Comment: @MikeG, I know $x^x$ is complex when $x < 0$. However, it is not clear what the $x^x$ in your numerator really refers to. If the real part of the numerator is positive, then the real part of the integrand is negative and the integral cannot be positive. I'm just trying to figure out what is the definition of your integral.

Comment: Let's put it like this: the series is Wolfram's series expansion at $x=0$ continued by imagining the evident pattern would be continued, so there is some info (up to order 5) that is Wolfram-provided, and the rest is my guess.

Comment: Well @achillehui all I have of the exercise is the equality in the question, I don't even have the book. It is an exercise a friend of mine emailed me a screenshot of, I got curious and asked this question. Maybe $x^x$ refers to the complex number. But then the notation with limits is not too clear, it would have to be specified the line integral is required. I agree on the real part, but the phrase sounds like an objection and I don't understand to what. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @MickG That is the power series for $e^z$ for $z=x\ln(x)$. It is valid as a complex power series centered at $z=0$

Comment: Wolfram approximates the answer to be non-real, although this proves nothing http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+int_%7B-infty%7D%5E0+x%5Ex%2F%28x%5E3-1%29+dx

Comment: @DavidPeterson what is the `series` for and why does it make Wolfram compute the integral approximately?

Comment: It uses power series to approximate the integral (if you type approximate instead, it defaults to series). I'm not sure how large it goes though. You can get similar functionality just by choosing largely negative limits http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_%7B-10000%7D%5E%7B0%7D+x%5Ex%2F%28x%5E3-1%29

Comment: I gotta thank the voters for giving me the Nice Question badge :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly enough, since this exercise seems off, I have found (using "proof by wolfram alpha") that

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 \dfrac{x}{x^3-1} dx = \dfrac{2\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}$$

So unless there's a notation disparity, it was probably a typo.

The above integral although it does not answer the question, is not hard

Comment: Yep, that is "easy". Just involves splitting the integrand into the sum of two fractions one for each factor of the denominator, standard way of dealing with rational functions, then integrating each one. One of the sub-integrals requires a not-too nice substitutions, two infinities cancel each other out, and voilà, $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{9}\frac{\pi}{2}$ is served. Oh… I have a half too much. But the arctangent _does_ tend to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, right? [Here's the splitting](http://bit.ly/wolframsplitint), and…

Comment: … evaluating the primitive in 0 and $-\infty$ has the logs cancel each other out, so what we are left with is $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{6}\arctan(\frac{2\cdot0+1}{\sqrt{3}})-\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{6}\lim \limits_{x\to-\infty}\arctan\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}= \frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{18}+\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{6}=\frac{2\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}$. Umm… I'll just check my calculations :).

Comment: There is _surely_ some kind of malfunction in MathJax there :).

Comment: Yep, the integral amounts to $\dfrac{\tan^{-1}(1/\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}} - \dfrac{-\pi/2}{\sqrt{3}} $

Comment: OK I found my mistake: hadn't changed the integration limits when making a substitution :). I have accepted your answer because it seems to solve the exercise, instead of accepting the one below which seems to address the question better, though it uses a Wolfram approximation and doesn't give a way to compute the integral.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry I must be missing something here because numerically I get a complex number$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{x^x}{x^3-1} = \int_0^{\infty}\frac{-(-x)^{-x}}{x^3+1}\approx -0.08459+0.64991 i$$

This is nowhere near $2\pi \sqrt{3}/9$.

Comment: Please see the edit. This exercise is quite strange indeed.

Comment: @GiulyB I saw your answer before you deleted it. I am posting this comment to tell you `\infty` is the infinity sign, in case you don't know, and also to ask whether or not you are the «friend of mine» who «emailed me a screenshot of» this exercise. One curiosity: does deleting a voted answer undo the rep changes the votes caused? So did you gain your 4 rep points back after deleting the answer?